# Where does Zookeeper keep Kafka ACL list?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Where does Zookeeper(or Kafka) keep its ACL list?

When you run scripts like `kafka-acls --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --list --topic test`, where does Zookeeper (or Kafka) get its list?

I am trying to find a file that stores all the ACLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access Zookeeper using the `zookeeper-shell.sh` script.
There is a znode called `kafka-acl` where information about ACLs for group, topic, cluster and so on are stored.
You can list for example information about ACLs on topics `ls /kafka-acl/Topic`.
Then getting information about a specific topic with `get /kafka-acl/Topic/test`.

Comment: I can see kafka-acls.sh under the bin folder, but can't find kafka-acl folder.

Comment: as I said you have to use `bin/zookeeper-shell.sh` to login into the ZK shell and you can see all the znodes. `kafka-acl` is not a folder is a znode on ZK. The ACL are not saved in the bin or other folders of the ZK installation, they are in the ZK znodes.

Comment: okay got it. Thank you.  I used zookeeper shell and did `ls /` but I guess kafka-acl is not yet been created or something. When I use `get /kafka-acl`, it says node does not exist.

Comment: did you create any ACLs using the kafka-acl.sh tool?

Comment: thx. I used kafka-acl.sh tool and now I can see kafka-acl node.

Answer (score 1):

Since I landed here searching for the same information and eventually stubbled my way to the answer, I thought to add some additional information. Since Apache Kafka ver 2.0, for topics with `patternType=PREFIXED`, the acls are stored under a zookeeper node `/kafka-acl-extended`, this is in addition to the `/kafka-acl` node which hold topic details of `patterType=LITERAL`.
For more details, read - [KAFKA-KIP-290](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-290%3A+Support+for+Prefixed+ACLs)

Answer (score 0):

## For additional reference :

If you look at your Zookeeper configuration file (`zoo.cfg` or `zookeeper.properties`), you will see the `dataDir` parameter, which tells you where the zookeeper stores its data. 
For example,

```
dataDir=/tmp/confluent.iSAdMTvO/zookeeper/data
```

[image]

So, Kafka ACL list will be stored there, but in order to control it or view it, use 
`zookeeper-shell` script. Because if you open the data to see, you won't be able to recognize it. See below for those who are curious.

[image]

Comment: I'm just curious. Why does the data look like above? If it is written in binary, I won't be able to see anything, but I see bits of English words and funny diagram.